# Animate an animated gif only while pressing the button

Tags: swiftui

This is my code :

```
struct Animation: View {
       var body: some View{
           Image("Animation.gif")
       }
   }
```

i have a gif image and i want this image to only be animated once a button click only, i need help!

and if there is no button click then it won't be animated thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, SwiftUI doesn't have anything that can do this. Instead, you should use an `@State` variable to track whether or not the button has been pressed. If it hasn't, show a non-animated image, and if it has, show a *different* image, but animated this time.

Something like this:

```
@State var buttonIsClicked = false

let nonAnimated = <static image>
let animated = <your gif>

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if buttonIsClicked {
            animated
        } else {
            nonAnimated
        }

      
        Button("Click to animate") {
            buttonIsClicked.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```